# Nginx Proxy Pass Nodejs to React Application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a front end of react and backend of node, for some reason it wont make the right request to the backend.

The error log given by nginx

```
111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, server: _, request: "GET /api/info HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/info"
```

I noticed that it makes the wrong request because the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/info` should be `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/info`

My default config

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/{{AppName}}/frontend/build;

        server_name {{myDomainName}};

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }
```

When I visit my website it just errors me out with Error 404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I noticed that it makes the wrong request because the
> http://127.0.0.1:5000/info should be http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/info

#### Action

Remove the '/' at the end of the proxy address

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; # remove the '/' at the end
}
```

#### Explain

From [nginx documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

> To pass a request to an HTTP proxied server, the proxy_pass directive
> is specified inside a location. For example:
>
> ```
> location /some/path/ {
>     proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/; 
> }
> ```
>
> Note that in the first example above, the address of the proxied server is followed by a URI, /link/.
> If the URI is specified along with the address, **it replaces the part
> of the request URI that matches the location parameter**. For example,
> here the request with the /some/path/page.html URI will be proxied to
> http://www.example.com/link/page.html

In your case, the URI is `/`, it replaces `/api/` in the request URI. So:
`http://yourserver/api/info` will be proxied to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/info`

Comment: I have solved this but you came first in posting the answer lol! Thank you!